# conversion from per year to per decade for time-series data

Tags: time-series

I was wondering if this logic makes sense.

I have a time series where the slope is -0.19 over 21 years, so the rate would be *-0.19 per year*. Now if I want a rate per decade, would it logically make sense to multiple the yearly rate by 10 to achieve a rate per decade?

For this example the rate would become *-1.9 per decade*. Does this logic make sense or do I need to make additional calculations to perform this conversion?

[random generated time series 2000-2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhQBg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can show this explicitly by using ["dimensional analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) with a conversion factor between years and decades.
$$\require{cancel}
-0.19 \frac{\text{units}}{\text{year}}
= -0.19 \frac{\text{units}}{\cancel{\text{year}}} \times 10 \frac{\cancel{\text{years}}}{\text{decade}}
= -1.9 \frac{\text{units}}{\text{decade}}$$